# Identifying youtube video url playing in webview in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, youtube, uiwebview

I have a webview control and request some search in Youtube.
There are lot's of result videos.
Users click one of them.
How to get the video URL playing?

Comment: checked webview delegate methods ?

Comment: can you find any ways for this please help me. my question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemBecameCurrent:)
                                             name:@"AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification"
                                           object:nil];


- (void)playerItemBecameCurrent:(NSNotification*)notification 
{
        AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [notification object];
        if(playerItem == nil) return;

        // Break down the AVPlayerItem to get to the path
        AVURLAsset *asset = (AVURLAsset*)[playerItem asset];
        NSURL *url = [asset URL]; // this is URL you need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the URL, try this code:

> NSString *currentURL = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location"];

But, if you want to get all events, just use webview delegate methods:

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
        NSString *URLString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
        //now you have the url;
       return YES;
   }
```